# Can I reuse an Observable inside a function?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My question is simple as a I've read many articles talking about Observables, Subscriptions and, of course, plenty ways to unsubscribe.

I have this code

```
merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
            .pipe(
                startWith({}),
                switchMap(() => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = true;
                    return this.ProductionService.get__customers()
                }),
                map((data: QueryResult<CustomerDTO>) => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = false;
                    this.items__length = data.totalCount;
                    return data.records;
                }),

            ).subscribe((data: CustomerDTO[]) => {
                this.d__source = data;
            });
```

This is inside a function called **getDataSource()**

It's inside a function because I want to manually refresh this dataSource (d__source) when I close a flyout. Let's imagine in my flyout adds a Customer and I want to close this flyout and refresh my **dataSource** to show the user the brand new created Customer.

My problem is, as you can see I have a sortChange and a MatPaginator but I have encountered and error I cannon solve.
I want to reuse this Observable for sorting or paginating. But when I close the flyout and call the **getDataSource** function again, the function is subscribing again and gets twice the Customers resulting in a double HTTP GET call to my API.

If I unsuscribe in the subscribe part like

```
const subscription = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
            .pipe(
                startWith({}),
                switchMap(() => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = true;
                    return this.ProductionService.get__customers()
                }),
                map((data: QueryResult<CustomerDTO>) => {
                    this.isLoadingResults = false;
                    this.items__length = data.totalCount;
                    return data.records;
                }),

            ).subscribe((data: CustomerDTO[]) => {
                this.d__source = data;
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            });
```

I cannot use the sort function.

Any idea would be appreciated, I'm stuck in this for a while.

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: How about to unify place for your observable (like a service, or parent component). And subscribe to it in any places you want. Just add "share()" to your pipe to prevent duplicate server calls.

Comment: Have you considered something like this? `merge(sortChange, page, closeFlyout)`; you'd subscribe to that obs once(e.g in `ngOnInit`), eventually unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy` and `closeFlyout` would be a `Subject` that will emit whenever the user closes the flyout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly solution would be to make 'const subscription' component-wide `this.subscription` and check it before subscribing `if (!this.subscription.closed) this.subscription.unsubscribe()` and then call again your subscription. But this is an ugly approach and there might be better alternatives.

Another would be to simply next what you already got. If on flyout close() you want to refresh your d__source, and this is dependent on `this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page`which I assume both are Subjects, and you have control over them, can you just next their current value? to just refresh the call... still kinda ugly but better than the previous one.

One last attempt that I would actually do, is to create a BehaviorSubject which is what triggers the d__source update... like so

```
private updateHandler = new BehaviorSubject({}); // notice it already starts with a value

...


    this.updateHandler // this onInit, and only once
        .pipe(
            switchMap(() => {
                this.isLoadingResults = true;
                return this.ProductionService.get__customers()
            }),
            map((data: QueryResult<CustomerDTO>) => {
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
                this.items__length = data.totalCount;
                return data.records;
            }),

        ).subscribe((data: CustomerDTO[]) => {
            this.d__source = data;
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        });
```

then in your component you can make your previous observables to next this behavior subject:

```
merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).subscribe(() => this.updateHandler.next());
```

this way they are doing the same.

You can control their closing with another Subject, let's call it 'this.destroy$'

```
private destroy$ = new Subject();
```

and then you can just pipe to all `takeUntil(this.destroy$)`(flavorfull), and add this onDestroy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

and finally, wherever you control your flyout closing, you simply `this.updateHandler.next()` and that should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, dude! Nice answer with several alternatives, but I'm encountering an error with the "better" solution. It says "this.updateHandler.next()" should be provided with an argument, but no clue what argument. Can you explain me, pls? Thanks again!

Comment: ahhh sorry, yes cuz BehaviorSubject always expects something to emit... if you pass null it should work, as you are not using the content of the emission but just the emission. Please let me know if it works for you

`this.updateHandler.next(null)`

Comment: I think you could also just make it a Subject and do the same things everywhere (adding back the pipe startWith)... hopefully I'm englihtening a bit on the uses of Subjects and Observables and not confusing you more with the different alternatives